# Booting a Graphical MIPS QEMU Machine

Tags: linux, mips, qemu

I would like to boot a QEMU MIPS architecture machine running some distribution of Linux. I have been looking through this documentation (https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/QEMU), but I am getting stuck at this part

```
[ralf@box qemu]$ qemu-system-mips -kernel /tftboot/192.168.0.1/vmlinux.bin -m 16 -nographic

(qemu) mips_r4k_init: start
mips_r4k_init: load BIOS '/usr/local/share/qemu/mips_bios.bin' size 131072
qemu: could not load MIPS bios '/usr/local/share/qemu/mips_bios.bin'

[ralf@box qemu]$

There currently is no MIPS BIOS file for QEMU (see firmware). However if passed a
 -kernel argument qemu will not call the firmware at all, so this does no harm at all. Therefore, a command such as
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/local/share/qemu/mips_bios.bin bs=1024 count=128
    will generate a firmware file that will do the job for now.
```

I am confused what arguement I am supposed to pass for kernel? Is that /usr/local/share/qemu/mips_bios.bin argument a compiled Linux image?

If possible, I would like the emulator to have a GUI. I am not sure how this is accomplished either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You no longer need to create a mips_bios.bin file.  If you have a file by that name in the same folder when you run qemu-system-mips it will pick it up.  I'd remove it if you do.  Here's the wiki link for a little history about it:

https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/QEMU

For a nice example of a mips specific kernel working with graphics and qemu please check this link out:

http://shadow-file.blogspot.com/2013/05/running-debian-mips-linux-in-qemu.html